# Use Checkbox to populate text field in PDF form

Tags: forms, pdf

I have a PDF form that I need to populate with "60" when the associated checkbox is checked. How do I write the Javascript? Or do I need JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the return value of the checkbox?

Although we can do something without knowing that, but we have to know the name of the target field.

One way to solve it would be in this line:

In the mouseUp event of the checkbox add the following JavaScript code:

```
if (event.target.value != "Off") {
this.getField("myTargetField").value = "60" ;
} else {
this.getField("myTargetField").value = "" ;
}
```

And that should do it.